# Push Notifications to PHP using Socket.IO / Node.JS

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io

So I've been researching this for a little bit, but was wondering how I would go about pushing notifications to a php page on the clients end to create something similar to facebook's notifications?

I've read that I will need to utilise Socket.IO installed by Node.JS. How do I do this?

Comment: check this http://krischeonline.com/2012/02/20/a-push-notification-relay-system-using-node-js-and-socket-io/

Comment: Try googling node js tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

If you're still interested, I made a small project interfacing NodeJS and PHP ; check [How to integrate nodeJS + Socket.IO and PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209717/how-to-integrate-nodejs-socket-io-and-php)