# Nodejs and socket.io using index.php instead of index.html

Tags: php, html, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Using the simple chat tutorial from the socket.io website I set up a server with nodejs and socket.io, but I wanted to be able to use it with my preexisting webpage, which has php in it and is therefor a .php file. When I changed the .html to .php I was not able to get the php file loaded like the html file does. I get: Error: ENOENT, stat '/index.php' Any ideas?

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.php');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: Let your message like this because the reader will not understand my anwser.

Comment: What do you mean? @A-312

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24765021/revisions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ENOENT` is `Error NO ENTry` that mean your file doesn't exist. You wrote:

```
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
```

But I think you want to do :

```
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.php');
```

If you change extansion file, you must to update filename in folder and in your code (js file).

---

But Nodejs can't execute your php code (you have to run php like a command with context argument).

[How to integrate nodeJS + Socket.IO and PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209717/how-to-integrate-nodejs-socket-io-and-php)

Comment: examples about this? please elaborate

Comment: @FernandoTorres The op forget to change '.php' to '.html' : https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24765021/revisions

Comment: @A-312 the question was asking about '.php', so it should remain in the question. I don't remember how I solved it, but your answer helped.

Comment: @Blubberguy22 you forgot to change .html by .php

Comment: @A-312 Honestly don't remember, that may have been the case.