# Send and receive socket.io messages through Php

Tags: php, socket.io

I've been looking everywhere and I can't find how I can connect my php code to socket.io. I know socket.io/node is meant to be the server-side but I would like to have my php code be able to send and receive socket messages. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Have a look here: https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet

Comment: You didn't specify if you were going to use node.js + socketio + php or just php and socketio. I only have experience of the first one and don't think the second even exists. http://elephant.io/ is an option for using both nodejs and php or you can just use michael's option which is not socketio but may be just what you need for websockets on php.

Comment: Are either of these SO questions useful? "[*Using PHP with Socket.io*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6398887/1364007)" or "[*How to integrate nodeJS + Socket.IO and PHP?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17209717/1364007)"