# Nodejs and wamp server confusion

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io, wamp

**The situation**

I have been developing in php and using wamp for the past 2 years. Then I come across a module to implement a chat system followed by instant notifications. So I go look it up and found this awesome "nodejs" that allows you to connect to connected users in realtime.

This guy [nodejs socket.io and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209717/how-to-integrate-nodejs-socket-io-and-php) uploaded a way to integrate nodejs socket.io and php without node server. 
So I downloaded his project (github) and ran it on my computer but it gave 
connection refused error from 8080 So,

I go to nodejs site and install nodejs on my system (windows). It automatically updated my environment variables and I could just go to my command line to run a example project as

```
path(...)node nodeServer.js
```

and then run the index file of the project from the shared link and it starts working. everything runs smooth and nice.

**MY QUESTION**

If without installing nodejs on my system I cannot run the node app in the small example project then how am I supposed to install nodejs on live server (apache) and use command line to start nodejs.

I know this might be too silly but I am really new to nodejs so I don't know if I can run node on live php server. If it is possible then can anyone tell me how can I do that ? or is it just an ideal situation and can't be done.

Answer (score 3):

Node.js do not need to be installed with Apache. Node.js itself provide a server that would listen on a port. You can use Apache or Nginx to use proxy. You can run your application without these server also.

Create a file index.js using the code below and run node index.js

```
var http = require('http');
  http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Open you browser and enter this url : http://127.0.0.1:1337/ You will see Hello World over there. In this case nodejs is listening on port 1337

Comment: see for "node index.js" to run, nodejs must be installed and envirionment variable must be set other wise there would be an error "node is not an internal or external command"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cloud or VPS or any kind of solution that allows you full control of stuff installed, you can just install node.js there and run what you need...

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installing-node.js-via-package-manager

some services will allow you to pick what gets installed... so you just pick nodejs and run it alongside your apache.

However, if you are using shared hosting solution, there is limited number of those actually even hosting node (if any) and solving this would be almost impossible for you.

**Second Edit:** Sorry for editing twice, but there is a thing with "no nodejs server" in mentioned stackoverflow post - there is actually a server and mentioned need to npm install certain modules... this is not right way to do this, but if you still want to try this you need node installed (and npm along with it) and then you need to npm isntall mentioned packages, add simple server file quoted in the post, run it and then have all you need for your chat...

If you need some help, ping me, but if this is time critical project, rather find some third party solution... and then learn about this one.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR** find a hosting service that'll give u admin and support firewall requests, or self host w/ a free dns subdomain and have a script update your ip so you dont have to pay for static.

**My Experiences**:

You can actually utilize node for input/output stream manipulation as well. Look at gulp and node for more info. Using bower and bluebird on top of a git project makes setting up apps very easy and quick via node.

As for using socket.io w/ a node/wamp setup, I've actually used this in the past. I had wamp installed on the server initially, but I used the apache directives to reverse proxy requests on 8080 to the node.js app from the client scripts.

I did have to install node separately, though, so you'll need something like ramnode maybe (I think they allow hosted apps like iis/mvc etc too).

Easiest hosting setup for development *imo* was self host wamp/node w/ a free subdomain from afraid.dns.

Otherwise ramnode gives you full access to admin features on your vm, i believe. So you may be able to install node there as long as you request firewall permissions when needed for xtra ports (socket.io used diff ports for requests on page so I didnt have to worry about CORs crap or anything).

Comment: Further, I believe the whole input/output stream is something from Ruby and Rails, but I'd have to double check (only read a bit of the PickAxe book, haven't used Ruby).