# Simple PHP + NodeJS approach for push notifications

Tags: php, node.js

Most of my website is PHP, and I want to start making a little better UI with live push notifications. I read a few articles and posts here as well, but non provide concrete examples. It's really hard to learn by yourself especially when Node still has no tutorials in abundance, mostly beginner's tutorials.
Let's say I have a PHP page: `post.php` which allow user to enter a post, and I use PDO to insert that post to the MySQL db.
What is the simple way to connect a node.js (on a different port) and listen to that PHP page, to then in turn show a notification on the navbar, for example?
I know I will need to use socket.io as well.

Comment: You can do one thing here is that create a route for live-notification in `node.js`, and send a `curl` request to that URL wherever you have to send notification.

Comment: Use below link for details on integrating PHP and node.js
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209717/how-to-integrate-nodejs-socket-io-and-php

Comment: Have you looked into https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-php ?